# how do I change my default country?

Tags: server, games

I've been using Ubuntu for about 3 months and my computer for some random reason wants to believe that I live in Haiti when in reality I live in the us, this problem has caused me not to be able to play games that don’t have servers in Haiti. would anyone happen to know how to solve my issue?

Comment: How did you find out that your computer believes you're in Haiti? Do you connect through a VPN?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

This should let you update your timezone

Answer (score 1):

Are you playing the games through a browser?

Some sites (e.g. Google Maps) use the browser locale to determine where you are from.

The firefox browser locale can be changed in about:config or using an addon such as [Locale Switcher Addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/locale-switcher/). You need to change your locale to English [US].